# Reading child nodes of xml file

Tags: c#, xml

I have created an Xml file with example contents as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<W-TIBCPTRs>
  <W-TIBCPTR>
    <TYPTRT>FDR2 R</TYPTRT>
    <CLAFCNO VALIDE="NON">5b1</CLAFCNO>
    <NUMCLI>0067781</NUMCLI>
    <TYPACT>D</TYPACT>
  </W-TIBCPTR>
  <W-TIBCPTR>
    <TYPTRT>FDR2 R</TYPTRT>
    <CLAFCNO>511</CLAFCNO>
    <NUMCLI>0068078</NUMCLI>
    <TYPACT>D</TYPACT>
  </W-TIBCPTR>
</W-TIBCPTRs>
```

i try this

```
   XmlNodeList rowElements = doc.SelectNodes("W-TIBCPTRs/W-TIBCPTR");
            foreach (XmlElement rowElement in rowElements)
            {

                foreach (XmlElement valueElement in rowElement.ChildNodes)
                {
                    strin[] k=valueElement.Name;
                }

            }
```

1. I need to selectNodes automaticly because I can have a xml file with different nodes
2. Stock childNodes in array, I need these values (TYPTRT,CLAFCNO,NUMCLI,TYPACT)

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to do with [Linq to Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx) (I suggest to use it instead old XmlDocument API):

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);

var result = from t in xdoc.Root.Elements("W-TIBCPTR")
             select new {
                TYPTRT = (string)t.Element("TYPTRT"),
                CLAFCNO = (string)t.Element("CLAFCNO"),
                NUMCLI = (string)t.Element("NUMCLI"),
                TYPACT = (string)t.Element("TYPACT")
             };
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    TYPTRT: "FDR2 R",
    CLAFCNO: "5b1",
    NUMCLI: "0067781",
    TYPACT: "D"
  },
  {
    TYPTRT: "FDR2 R",
    CLAFCNO: "511",
    NUMCLI: "0068078",
    TYPACT: "D"
  }
]
```

NOTE: Currently you are selecting element's name. If you want to get inner text of all sub-elements in array, you can use:

```
string[] items = rowElement.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>()
                           .Select(e => e.InnerText)
                           .ToArray();
```

That will return array of four strings for each W-TIBCPTR element in your sample xml. Same with Linq to Xml will look like:

```
var result = from t in xdoc.Root.Elements("W-TIBCPTR")
             select t.Elements().Select(e => e.Value).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Linq to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx)

```
var doc= XDocument.Load(<path>);

var values = from c in doc.Descendants("W-TIBCPTR")       
             select new
             {
                  TYPTRT = c.Element("TYPTRT").Value,
                  CLAFCNO = c.Element("CLAFCNO").Value
                  NUMCLI = c.Element("NUMCLI").Value
                  TYPACT = c.Element("TYPACT").Value
             });
```

Comment: i need to select XmlNodeList rowElements = doc.SelectNodes("W-TIBCPTRs/W-TIBCPTR"); dynamcly i mean this "W-TIBCPTRs/W-TIBCPTR" because i upload the xml file and i generate the html file